# Discourse - Ruby 2.0 / Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, discourse

I know this is not the right type of question for Stack Overflow (please forgive me), but I've spent hours trying to get Discourse to run on my machine. It was working before, but I upgraded to Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4 and now I simply can't get it working due to various errors (mounting NFS, Syck deprecated, TheRubyRacer not installing properly).

I tackled these one by one, and now when I SSH into vagrant it says cannot find the gemfile when I do bundle install. I think I may have altered something and it's not "SSH-ing" into the proper folder, but I did a lot of things based on what I googled / found on stackoverflow and am kind of stuck.

I know this is a very vague / poorly structured question, but I'm still new to programming and just wondering, does Discourse work with Ruby 2.0/Rails 4 and can someone point me in the right direction regarding how to tell if I somehow broke my SSH command?

Comment: This might be a better question for http://superuser.com.

Comment: I don't know — this all seems pretty developer-centric to me. Modifying software software to run with development builds of Rails is not really an end-user concern in general.

Comment: see: http://meta.discourse.org/t/when-should-we-upgrade-to-rails-4/4046 we dual boot now

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Discourse source code and mainly based on the [Gemfile/Gemfile.lock](https://github.com/discourse/discourse)
the rails version is   **Rails v3.2.12** and probably they are using **Ruby 1.9.x**

**Edit 1**
Based on [Rails's Travis CI Builds](https://travis-ci.org/rails/rails) it looks that rails supports **ruby 2.0**. I don't know if Rails 3.2.12 supports it - but my guess is that you should have little or no issue to run Discourse on Ruby 2.0.

**Edit 2**
Moreover it looks that [Discourse Builds against Ruby 2.0 without problems](https://travis-ci.org/discourse/discourse).

Comment: Well, at least [Ruby 2.0 is doable](http://meta.discourse.org/t/we-are-running-ruby-2-0-in-production/4965).

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the root directory of the app after you ssh?

```
cd /vagrant
```